# Is it possible to ban users that aren't in the discord server?

Tags: discord.js

I recently started on making my discord bot in javascript. I made my own bot have the power of banning people and it successfully bans people that are IN the server, but I wanted to know if there was a way I can ban people that left the server or even never joined the server.

```js
const bUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));

if(!bUser) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find user.");

message.guild.member(bUser).ban(banreason);

return message.channel.send("User " + bUser + " was banned");
```

When I ban someone not in the server it says: "Couldn't find user."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Guild.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ban) method which uses a User instead of a GuildMember.

Example:

```js
// async context

try {
  const user = message.mentions.users.first() || await client.fetchUser(args[0]);
  if (!user) return await message.channel.send('Unable to find user.');

  const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason provided';

  await message.guild.ban(user, { reason: reason });
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I can now ban people that are not in the server! Do you happen to know why I can't check user permissions like this: 
```js
if(bUser.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You cannot ban that person");
```

Comment: You must check the permissions of a GuildMember, not a User. Define a `member` variable as `message.guild.member(user)`, and then use that when checking permissions (keep in mind it might not exist if the user isn't in the guild). You'll also have to make sure the user isn't the guild owner or the bot.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I've set it in a try catch so it will won't give a error if they are in not the server.

Comment: It won't continue with the code if they're not with that setup. You could change your `if` statement to: `if (member && member.hasPermission(...))`. Then, if they aren't in the server, the permission check will be ignored and won't cause an issue.

Comment: I had it in another way that worked too, but this seems way easier and shorter thanks again!