# How to ban someone that's not in the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was wondering if it's possible to ban someone via `User ID`. Normally, to ban someone, you'd use a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and the [`.ban()` method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban):

```js
GuildMember.ban()
```

**However**, if a user is not in the guild you want to ban them from, it's impossible to get their `GuildMember` object. Is there an alternate method?

---

Using the actual Discord program, it *is* possible to ban someone before they join by mentioning them with their `User ID` (for example: `<@123456789012345678>`). Then, you can right-click the mention, and then ban them:

[image: example]

Is there a way to replicate this with `discord.js`?

---

During my research on the problem, I stumbled upon [someone asking the same question as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56297539/is-it-possible-to-ban-users-that-arent-in-the-discord-server). The accepted answer was to use the `Guild.ban` function.

However, since I couldn't find the method in the [`Guild` class docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild), and the same answer used `fetchUser()` (a deprecated function), I came to the conclusion that it would only work in `discord.js v11`.

Since it was previously a function in an earlier version, I'm sure there's probably still a way to do it now that I haven't found.

---

Lastly, I know that I could just add the `User ID` to an array, and whenever the `guildMemberAdd` event is emitted I could check their `User ID` against that array, but I'd still like to know if banning a member by `User ID` is possible. Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit:** [Docs for the v11 `Guild.ban()` function](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=ban)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In v12 discord.js moved such methods which interact with guild members all to the [`GuildMemberManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) class, accessible via [`guild.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members).

The method you're looking for is [`GuildMemberManager.ban(id)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=ban). There's an example on the docs:

```
guild.members.ban('84484653687267328')
  .then(user => console.log(`Banned ${user.username || user.id || user} from ${guild.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: excellent answer, thank you!